# Linux boot hangs: [Firmware bug] ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness

Tags: linux, acpi, lubuntu

I have an old Win XP NEC laptop and I tried to boot a live usb with Lubuntu 14.10 to install Lubuntu, but when I tried to boot the live USB, after about a minute the boot process hangs at a line that says:
[Firmware Bug] ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness.

I left it there for ~ 15 minutes and it was still stuck there. I tried rebooting, unplugging everything and booting, but nothing worked. I can only boot to windows XP. I cannot even boot to a Linux terminal. I've looked at many different StackExchange articles and I've tried Google. Please help!

-Keith

Comment: Can you try to append to kernel acpi_backlight=vendor ?

Comment: Thanks @taliezin and @gogoud! A combonation of both your reccomendations worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your old laptop has a Pentium M or Celeron M CPU? Try adding boot option `forcepae` at the grub menu when your live usb boots. More info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu-fake-PAE). If this doesn't work you might have more success with Lubuntu (or Ubuntu) 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the _BQC function in a DSDT override;

```
Method (_BQC, 0, NotSerialized)  // _BQC: Brightness Query Current
{
    Return (0x1E)
}
```